# Is there a way to transform table data into json while running puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, puppeteer

i'm facing some problem trying to convert html tables to json using **puppeteer** and **tabletojson**.

What i'm doing it's very simple, with puppeteer went to chrome, created a new page and than started typing some words and hitted the search button. When puppeteer completes this task a table appears on the screen, and i think that's why **tabletojson** keeps showning me an empty array. It isn't running with **puppeteer** but running after **puppeteer** accessing the same url without any previous **puppeteer** interaction which doesn't have any table to read yet.

What i'm asking is: Is there a way to get this table as json while running puppeteer? Or may be is there some way to run tabletojson asynchronous while scraping?

```html
const puppteer = require('puppeteer')
const tabletojson = require('tabletojson')

async function letscrap()
{
some puppeteer ....
  const browser = await puppteer.launch(
        {
            headless: false,
            defaultViewport: null
        }
    )
    
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  const url = "https://someurl.com/..."
  
 
some tabletojson ....

// here the ideia is to get json from tables...
  // at this point what happens is that it doesn't return anything due to this...
  
        await tabletojson.convertUrl(
            'https://someurl.com/...',
            {stripHtmlFromCells: false, stripHtmlFromCells: true },
            function(tablesAsJson) {
              console.log(tablesAsJson);
            }
        );
        
}

letscrap()
```

The HTML source:

```html
<form method="post" action="/ConsultaPlanosConsumidor/pages/home.xhtml;jsessionid=bSbNLIiZ7pWWf7mgDl_MIw-F9QPRpVbNlo8johjO.ansprjboss01a:consulta-planos-consumidor-01a" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

<!-- 

Some inputs right here
and... 

-->
<button id="formHome:tabOperadora:j_idt99" name="formHome:tabOperadora:j_idt99" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Search</span>
</button>


<!-- 

When you hit "Search" it "appends" to it's div with a table.

-->

</form>
```

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Please provide more detailed code, especially within the search button method. Is it `POST` or `GET` method? And if you could, please provide the HTML source of the search result or at least explain the big picture of HTML structure. If you don't mind, you can provide the URL of search result.

Comment: Hello there! Here are the url http://www.ans.gov.br/ConsultaPlanosConsumidor/. I'm actually trying to scrap this out just to get this tables automaticly. It's in portuguese, so to get the same response i'm trying have you'll need to hit "Por Plano" button at the top > "Comercialização" set to "Liberada" > "Abrangência" set to "Nacional" > than hit "Pesquisar"...It will give you a table which i'm trying to convert into json.  Hope it hepls

Comment: I've made an answer below, please check it, and if you like, choose it as the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the table you're collecting wasn't the right one.
I've found that in the result page, there are at least 5 tables.
So you have to find the right selector for the containing data table.
The right selector is `table[role="grid"]`. And you can scrape all pages in the search result without using tabletojson. I've made this script to write the search result table data into a CSV file.

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer')
const fs = require ('fs-extra')

const selectElementID_first = 'formHome:tabOperadora:solbSituacoesPrincipais'
const selectElementID_second = 'formHome:tabOperadora:solbAbrangenciasGeograficas'

const selectedOption_first = 'Liberada'
const selectedOption_second = 'Nacional'

const saveFileCSV = 'porpiano.csv'

let lastPage = 0

;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({
        headless : false,
        devtools : false
    })

    const [page] = await browser.pages ()

    const open = await page.goto ('http://www.ans.gov.br/ConsultaPlanosConsumidor/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 })

    const porPianoClick = await page.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector('a[href="#formHome:tabOperadora:panelPorPlano"]').click() )

    // FIRST SELECT OPTION

    while ( !await page.evaluate( selectElementID_first => document.querySelector(`div[id="${selectElementID_first}"]`).classList.contains('ui-state-focus'), selectElementID_first ) ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('Tab')
        await page.waitFor(300)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Space')

    while ( await page.evaluate( selectElementID_first => document.querySelector(`div[id="${selectElementID_first}_panel"]`).style.display === 'none', selectElementID_first ) ) {
        await page.waitFor(300)
    }

    while ( await page.evaluate( (selectElementID_first, selectedOption_first) => document.querySelector(`div[id="${selectElementID_first}_panel"] ul > li.ui-state-highlight`).innerText !== selectedOption_first, selectElementID_first, selectedOption_first ) ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
        await page.waitFor(300)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Enter')

    await page.waitFor(1000)


    // SECOND SELECT OPTION

    while ( !await page.evaluate( selectElementID_second => document.querySelector(`div[id="${selectElementID_second}"]`).classList.contains('ui-state-focus'), selectElementID_second ) ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('Tab')
        await page.waitFor(300)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Space')

    while ( await page.evaluate( selectElementID_second => document.querySelector(`div[id="${selectElementID_second}_panel"]`).style.display === 'none', selectElementID_second ) ) {
        await page.waitFor(300)
    }

    while ( await page.evaluate( (selectElementID_second, selectedOption_second) => document.querySelector(`div[id="${selectElementID_second}_panel"] ul > li.ui-state-highlight`).innerText !== selectedOption_second, selectElementID_second, selectedOption_second ) ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
        await page.waitFor(300)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Enter')

    await page.waitFor(1000)


    await page.evaluate( () => document.querySelector('div[id="formHome:tabOperadora:panelPorPlano"] button[type="submit"]').click() )

    await fs.writeFile ( saveFileCSV, 'Número do Registro / Código do Plano, Nome Comercial do Plano, Segmentação Assistencial, Tipo de Contratação, Abrangência Geográfica, Tipo de Plano, Comercialização\n' )

    const loadTableGrid = async () => {
        // WAIT FOR PAGE LOADING

        await page.waitForSelector('span.ui-paginator-current', {timeout: 0})

        while ( lastPage === await page.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector('span.ui-paginator-current').innerText.split(' de ')[0] ) ) {
            await page.waitFor(250)
        }


        await page.waitForSelector('table[role="grid"]', {timeout: 0})

        // SCRAPE DATA

        var tableDataPage = await page.evaluate( () => {

            var tableDataPage = []

            var tableDataColumn1 = []
            var tableDataColumn2 = []
            var tableDataColumn3 = []
            var tableDataColumn4 = []
            var tableDataColumn5 = []
            var tableDataColumn6 = []
            var tableDataColumn7 = []

            document.querySelectorAll('td[role="gridcell"]:nth-of-type(1)').forEach( tableData => tableDataColumn1.push( tableData.innerText ) )
            document.querySelectorAll('td[role="gridcell"]:nth-of-type(2)').forEach( tableData => tableDataColumn2.push( `"${tableData.innerText}"` ) )
            document.querySelectorAll('td[role="gridcell"]:nth-of-type(3)').forEach( tableData => tableDataColumn3.push( tableData.innerText ) )
            document.querySelectorAll('td[role="gridcell"]:nth-of-type(4)').forEach( tableData => tableDataColumn4.push( tableData.innerText ) )
            document.querySelectorAll('td[role="gridcell"]:nth-of-type(5)').forEach( tableData => tableDataColumn5.push( tableData.innerText ) )
            document.querySelectorAll('td[role="gridcell"]:nth-of-type(6)').forEach( tableData => tableDataColumn6.push( tableData.innerText ) )
            document.querySelectorAll('td[role="gridcell"]:nth-of-type(7)').forEach( tableData => tableDataColumn7.push( tableData.innerText ) )

            for ( let num in tableDataColumn1 ) {
                tableDataPage[num] =
                    [
                        tableDataColumn1[num],
                        tableDataColumn2[num],
                        tableDataColumn3[num],
                        tableDataColumn4[num],
                        tableDataColumn5[num],
                        tableDataColumn6[num],
                        tableDataColumn7[num]
                    ]
            }

            return tableDataPage
        })

        // WRITE COLLECTED DATA TO CSV FORMAT

        for ( let row in tableDataPage ) {
            await fs.appendFile ( saveFileCSV, `${tableDataPage[row]}\n` )
            await page.waitFor(100)
        }

        var paginatorValue = await page.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector('span.ui-paginator-current').innerText.split(' de ') )

        lastPage = paginatorValue[0]

        if ( paginatorValue[0] !== paginatorValue[1] ) {
            await page.evaluate ( () => document.querySelector('a[aria-label="Next Page"]').click() )
            await loadTableGrid ()
        } else {
            console.log ('SCRAPE ALL TABLE DATA FINISHED\nCLOSING PUPPETEER BROWSER!')
            await browser.close ()
        }
    }

    await loadTableGrid ()

})()
```

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you.